# SetConsoleCursorPosition and cout vs WriteConsoleOutput

Tags: c++, winapi, console-application, windows-console

I'm planning to do a simple game using the console. For updating my character to a new position, should I use [`WriteConsoleOutput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsoleoutput), or should I combine calling [`SetConsoleCursorPosition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolecursorposition) and `cout`? Is one better than the other? Or is it a matter of personal preference?

EDIT: I wrote `SetCursorPos` instead of `SetConsoleCursorPosition`.

Comment: Standard C++ offers no means of setting the cursor position, or doing other console manipulations, so you wil need to use the console API.

Comment: Note that `SetCursorPos` moves the mouse cursor around the screen, not the "caret" in a console window. I suggest you actually read the docs for the functions you propose to use.

Comment: The console is slow, the cost of the process interop with conhost.exe (the actual process that owns the window) is pretty high.  Minimizing the interop traffic tends to be useful.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I'm using Windows.h header file which, i think has some console manipulations. I came across it when i was looking for messing with consoles along with PDCurses and ncurses.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Yea, one of my problems is that i don't fully understand the functions, thats why i'm here C: AND it is SetConsoleCursorPosition() function and i wrote SetCursorPos by mistake sorry.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm in highschool and i'm not focusing on optimal speed (but i don't want to have poor code). I've heard that consoles are bad for making games but i don't want to try too hard and i'm just messing around with things i can do with C++.

Comment: You would probably see better performance by updating the entire console screen buffer with a single `WriteConsoleOutput` call. The game logic would modify the in-process buffer, and a worker thread would periodically write this buffer to the screen, maybe at 20 FPS or so.

Comment: @eryksun Right now i'm just using WriteConsoleOutput to replace one character rather than the whole block. Can you explain whats an worker thread? If i'm right, i think it's the process which updates the screen while the other does the calculations part and sends it to the worker thread.

Comment: A Process is a container -- a private address space and associated global state such as environment variables and handles. The actual work of processing is executed by a Thread, each of which is attached to a Process and has its own execution context. There can be far more active threads than available cores, so the system switches context between them according to a scheduling algorithm that tries to balance the load. A new Process starts with a single Thread -- the main thread -- but it can create additional threads for background and I/O processing. That's what I'm calling a worker thread.

Comment: @eryksun I see, so it's better to update the screen at the constant rate rather than updating when ever i get an input?

Comment: I said you would "*probably* see better performance" by updating the screen with a single call rather than making multiple calls to repeatedly redraw just the sprites and background that are changing. You'll have to try and compare.

Comment: Trying to write a simple game using the console makes for a tough challenge. Write a GUI application instead. It'll be so much easier, not having to deal with intricacies of a subsystem that wasn't meant to display graphics or deal with asynchronous input.

Comment: @eryksun I see, thanks for replying and editing my post C:

Comment: @IInspectable I kinda know GUI application would be easier and better but i want to try a program with the things i have learned from school (which is too basic) and don't want to move from console unless i've finished this game and i have free time to mess more.

Comment: Having written several text-mode UI console games in the past I can only recommend to write a GUI game first, and try to implement a console-based clone later. A console-based game is just so much harder to do, and you'll find yourself wasting lots of time getting even the basics straight (as evidenced by this question).

Comment: @IInspectable I see, any software suggestions?